# Translating between hibernate and thrift

Tags: java, generics

This is neither related to hibernate nor thrift itself.

I'm developing a Java application where I fetch data from database through Hibernate and want to serve those objects through apache thrift service. So far I have only few models, but for each of them I have to iterate through the hibernate object list and construct list of thrift obects.

For example, consider following pieces of code (this is the thrift service handler, which takes hibernate collection as IN and returns thrift collection):

```
@Override
public List<TOutcome> getUserOutcomes(int user_id) throws TException {
    List<Outcome> outcomes = this.dataProvider.getOutcomesByUserId(user_id);
    List<TOutcome> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Iterator iterator = outcomes.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Outcome outcome = (Outcome) iterator.next();
        TOutcome t_outcome = new TOutcome(
                (double) (Math.round(outcome.getAmount() * 100)) / 100,
                outcome.getUser().getName(),
                String.valueOf(outcome.getCategory().getName()));
        t_outcome.setComment(outcome.getComment());
        result.add(t_outcome);
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public List<TIncome> getUserIncomes(int user_id) throws TException {
    List<Income> incomes = this.dataProvider.getIncomesByUserId(user_id);
    List<TIncome> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Iterator iterator = incomes.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Income income = (Income) iterator.next();
        TIncome t_income = new TIncome(
                (double) (Math.round(income.getAmount() * 100)) / 100,
                income.getUser().getName(),
                String.valueOf(income.getCategory().getName()));
        t_income.setComment(income.getComment());
        result.add(t_income);
    }
    return result;
}
```

`Outcome`,`Income` - these are Hibernate annotated classes and `TOutcome`,`TIncome` - are related thrift objects (which share 80-90% of fields).

The "DRY" principle is violated now, since this code is very, very similar. I would like to provide one generic method to iterate hibernate objects and return thrift objects. I was thinking of generics and design patterns.

In dynamic languages I could just use strings to build class name and construct objects (there's no type checking). I guess there is a possibility to do similar stuff in Java, using generics, but I'm not sure where should I start at.

Comment: Could you refactor code to use one class for Outcome and Income common data? You could use inheritance or mixin.

Comment: @kan Its not that easy. [1] there is no inheritance in thrift and [2] other models are not that similar to each other (User, Category and Outcome - almost nothing in common - but the iteration stuff is the same).

Comment: You could design a concoction using Java Reflection assuming that the fields have the same name or some matching element to help you, but I think @kan's suggestion probably helps you better

Comment: Different models have totally different fields (User vs Income - nothing in common). Don't you guys think that a factory + inheritance would be better than only inheritance? It'd have one method `translate` overriden with different parameter types: `translate(Outcome)->TOutcome`, `translate(Income)->TIncome`, `translate(User)->TUser`, etc. And if I managed to find base classes for both Hibernate and Thrift data objects - inheritance would simplify iterating collections?

Answer (score 1):

As I see only about 10 lines of code are common, and they are common accidently, not by business requirements. Of course you could refactor code to extract a few interfaces: one for data provider to choose between `getOutcomesByUserId` and `getIncomesByUserId`, another for object factory - either `new TIncome` or `new TOutcome`. Or use reflection. However these variants of the code will look more complex and harder to support. I think at the moment it is good enough, it doesn't worth to change. Expect better to use `for(Income income : incomes)` instead of the iterator boilerplate.

However, there are some libraries which could significantly simplify the mapping if you have a complex but similar data structures to map, e.g. have a look at the [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).